# Transposing data based on unique ID - awk

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

I really hope you can help. I am completely new to (g)awk and I have been fighting with it for the last two weeks.

My original file is as follows - there is column with a unique Id and another with unique names. Subsequent columns are various courses and each field contains (when not empty) a mark for each course and for each student. So each student has only one mark for each course:

```
Id  Name        Course1 Course2 Course3 Course4 Course5
1   John           55
2   George                                         63
4   Alex                          64
1   John                                   74
3   Emma           63
2   George                64
4   Alex                                   60
2   George         29                   
3   Emma                                           69
1   John                  67
3   Emma                  80
4   Alex           57
2   George                                 91
1   John                          81
1   John                                           34
3   Emma                          75
2   George                        89
4   Alex                                           49
3   Emma                                   78
4   Alex                  69
5   TERRY                 67
6   HELEN                         39
```

This is what I want to achieve - transpose data i.e marks, based on the unique ID and place the marks below each corresponding course like below:

```
Id  Name        Course1 Course2 Course3 Course4 Course5
1   John          55      69       64     60      49
2   George        29      64       89     91      63
3   Emma          63      80       75     78      69
4   Alex          57      69       64     60      49
5   TERRY                 67
6   HELLEN                         39
```

This is what I managed to get so far:

```
Id  Name        Course1 Course2 Course3 Course4 Course5
1   John          55            
2   George        29            
3   Emma          63            
4   Alex          57    
5   TERRY
6   HELLEN      
1   John                  69            
2   George                64            
3   Emma                  80            
4   Alex                  69            
5   TERRY                 67
6   HELLEN
1   John                           64
2   George                         89
3   Emma                           75
4   Alex                           64
5   TERRY
6   HELLEN                         39
                                        ...and so on
```

It is really a bit tricky for me to achieve based to what I already know on awk (please note I am not interested in sed/perl e.t.c. based solutions). 
If it is to provide some help (preferably NOT an one liner) may I ask to be a bit descriptive as I am interested in the solution as much as I am in the method itself.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

EDIT
Here is the code I wrote to reach the last stage (and where I got stuck)

```
#!/bin/bash

files3="*.csv"
for j in $files3
do
    #echo "processing $j..."
    fi13=$(awk -F" " '(NR==1){field13=$13;}{print field13}' ./work1/test1YA.csv)
    fi14=$(awk -F" " '(NR==1){field14=$14;}{print field14}' ./work1/test1YA.csv)
    fi15=$(awk -F" " '(NR==1){field15=$15;}{print field15}' ./work1/test1YA.csv)
    fi16=$(awk -F" " '(NR==1){field16=$16;}{print field16}' ./work1/test1YA.csv)

#   awk -F" " 'BEGIN{OFS=" ";RS="\n"}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12}' "$j" >> ./work1/test2YA.csv
    awk -F" " -v f13="$fi13" -v f14="$fi14" -v f15="$fi15" -v f16="$fi16" '{if($13==f13){$13=$6;$14=$15=$16=""}if($13==f14){$14=$6;$13=$15=$16=""}if($13==f15){$15=$6;$13=$14=$16=""}if($13==f16){$16=$6;$13=$14=$15=""}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16}}' "$j" >> ./work1/test2YA.csv

done;

awk -F" " 'BEGIN{print "ID","Title","FirstName","MiddleName","LastName","FinalMarks","Status","Username","Campus","Code","Programme","Year","course1","course2","course3","course4"}{print}' ./work1/test2YA.csv >> ./work1/test3YA.csv
```

Comment: Can you paste the code that produces your half-way solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for gnu awk:

**course.awk**

```
BEGIN { # setup field width for constant field splitting
        FIELDWIDTHS = "2 2 12 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7"
        # setup sort order (by id)
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
      }

NR == 1 { # print header
          print
          next
        }

      {
        # add ids to names
        names[ $1 ] = $3

        # store under id and course number the mark if it is present
        for( c = 1; c <= 5; c++ ) {
          field = 2+ (c*2)
          if( $(field) !~ /^ *$/ ) {
            marks[ $1, c ] = $(field)
          }
        }
      }

END   {
        # output
        for( id in names ) {
          printf("%-4s%-12s%7s %7s %7s %7s %7s\n",id, names[ id ], marks[ id, 1], marks[ id, 2], marks[ id, 3], marks[ id, 4], marks[ id, 5])
        }
      }
```

Use it like this: `awk -f course.awk your_file`.

The fact that the input is not tab delimited, but has fixed column width make is a bit unelegant:

- use of `FIELDWIDTHS` and `%Ns` where N is *derived* from the FIELDWIDTHS
- FIELDWIDTHS take into account the empty column between ID and Name, Course1 and Course2, ...
- the check if a mark is present: `if( $(field) !~ /^ *$/ )` checks if field does not consist entirely of spaces.

Comment: Perfect! Solution.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick and detailed answers. I accept @Lars Fiscer answer because he was the first to answer with comments and I learned about FIELDWIDTHS and PROCINFO (it seems I cannot "vote" for accepted answer as my reputation is too low, or "thump-up" other answers as they were all very useful)!

I had to modify slightly the answer for my needs (my source file is tabulated and I had no need for fieldwidths, procinfo and printf).

Again many many thanks to everybody. It is very kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an approximation in awk:

```
NR==1{
    for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)
    {
        head=head $x"\t";
    }
    print head
}
NR>1{
    for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)
    {
        students[$1"\t"$2]=students[$1"\t"$2] "\t"$i;
    }
}
END{
    for (stu in students)
    {
        print stu,students[stu];
    }
}

Id      Name    Course1 Course2 Course3 Course4 Course5
5       TERRY   67
4       Alex    64      60      57      49      69
1       John    55      74      67      81      34
6       HELEN   39
3       Emma    63      69      80      75      78
2       George  63      64      29      91      89
```

Comment: logic seems to be wrong based on the output.  Check TERRY and HELEN.

Comment: @karakfa Thank you, I am aware that Helen score should be in the "course3" column  and Terry score in "course2" column. That is the reason why I said it was an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

same ideas, perhaps simpler

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS="16 8 8 8 8 8"} 
       NR==1{print;next} 
        NR>1{keys[$1]; 
             for(i=2;i<=6;i++) 
                {gsub(" ","",$i); 
                 if($i) a[$1,i]=$i}} 
         END{for(k in keys) 
                {printf "%16s",k; 
                 for(i=2;i<=6;i++) printf "%-8s",a[k,i]; 
                 print ""}}' file


Id  Name        Course1 Course2 Course3 Course4 Course5
3   Emma        63      80      75      78      69
4   Alex        57      69      64      60      49
6   HELEN                       39
5   TERRY               67
1   John        55      67      81      74      34
2   George      29      64      89      91      63
```

you can sort the output as well by piping to `sort -n`

```
... | sort -n

Id  Name        Course1 Course2 Course3 Course4 Course5
1   John        55      67      81      74      34
2   George      29      64      89      91      63
3   Emma        63      80      75      78      69
4   Alex        57      69      64      60      49
5   TERRY               67
6   HELEN                       39
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS, 2D arrays, and sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    print
    split($0,f,/\S+\s*/,s)
    for (i=1;i in s;i++) {
        w[i] = length(s[i])
        FIELDWIDTHS = FIELDWIDTHS (i>1?" ":"") w[i]
    }
    next
}
{
    sub(/\s*$/,"  ")
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i ~ /\S/) {
            val[$1][i] = $i
        }
    }
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (id in val) {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            printf "%*s", w[i], val[id][i]
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Id  Name        Course1 Course2 Course3 Course4 Course5
1   John            55      67      81      74     34
2   George          29      64      89      91     63
3   Emma            63      80      75      78     69
4   Alex            57      69      64      60     49
5   TERRY                   67
6   HELEN                           39
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this. This works in plain-old awk (doesn't use FIELDWIDTHS), and it automatically adjusts to different numbers of fields (i.e. add a `Course7` column and you should be fine). Also, you can point it at multiple files, and it should process each one separately.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Initialize variables on the first record of each input file
# (and also print the header)
#
FNR <= 1 {
  print
  delete name
  delete score
  next
}

# Process each line.
#
{
  id = substr($0, 0, 16)    #
  name[id]                 # Store the unique identifier in an array
  pos = 0                  #

  # Step through the score fields until we hit the end of the line,
  # storing scores in another array.
  do {
    score[id, pos] += substr($0,17+pos*8,8) +0
    printf("id='%s' pos=%s value=%s total=%s\n", id, pos, substr($0,17+pos*8,8)+0, score[id, pos] );
  } while (17+(++pos)*8 < length())
}

# Keep track of our maximum number of fields
pos>max { max=pos }

# Finally, generate our (randomly sorted) output.
END {
  for (id in name) {        # Step through the records...
    printf("%-12s", id);
    for (i=0; i<max; i++) { # Step through the fields...
      if (score[id, i]==0) score[id, i]=""
      printf("%-8s", score[id, i]);
    }
    printf("\n")
  }
}
```

It's a bit long but I think it's easier to understand what it does.